# Adding a custom style to content editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-management

I have the standard content editor that uses an iFrame as the text area and then onchange of dropdowns it performs:

idContent.document.execCommand(cmd,"",opt);

where "idContent" is the iFrame.

One of the dropdowns is supposed to be style but it performs a "formatBlock" command.

I have a custom style sheet.  Is there a way for me to put styles that I've created into this style drop down?  If not, I can have another dropdown for these custom styles but what is the command name to set those styles?

Here is the dropdown and javascript that I'm currently using:

```
 <select onchange="cmdExec('formatBlock',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0">
<option selected>Style</option>
    <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
    <option value="Heading 1">Heading 1</option>
    <option value="Heading 2">Heading 2</option>
    <option value="Heading 3">Heading 3</option>
    <option value="Heading 4">Heading 4</option>
    <option value="Heading 5">Heading 5</option>
    <option value="Address">Address</option>
    <option value="Formatted">Formatted</option>
    <option value="Definition Term">Definition Term</option>
  </select>

 function cmdExec(cmd,opt) 
    {   
    idContent.document.execCommand(cmd,"",opt);
         idContent.focus();
    }
```

Comment: What is "the standard content editor"?  What CMS are you using?  Without this context your question could mean anything, since it's about how to use your particular CMS rather than about javascript in the abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to link a stylesheet to the document you are currently editing, assuming you have in the iframe a document in designMode. The stylesheet can contain the styles you like that you can apply by altering element CSS classnames or wrapping in an HTML element that has a classname. However you will not be able to apply it using the designMode commands. You'll have to use selections & ranges, and manually change the HTML mark-up to get your desired styling applied.

Read the following article on the general commands that you can apply: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Midas

The following articles will explain advanced editing techniques using Selections & Ranges:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range